# Haskell servant wai middleware not working properly

Tags: haskell, middleware, servant

So, I want to add two wai middlewares to my servant server. One middleware for serving static files, and one for logging.

I have my api defined (`router`) and this is how I start my server :

```
webServer :: IO ()
webServer = run 80 (middleware $ router)
```

And here is how I defined my `middleware` :

```
middleware :: Application -> Application
middleware = do
  logStdoutDev
  staticPolicy $ addBase "static"
```

Now, if I put `logStdoutDev` first than I can't serve static files, but if I put `staticPolicy` first, than I can serve static files but I loose ability to log events (basically they get ignored).

Question is really, how to properly combine `wai` middleware in servant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compose two middleware's: `logStdoutDev` and `staticPolicy $ addBase "static"`. But what did you do?

```
middleware = do
    logStdoutDev
    staticPolicy $ addBase "static"
```

It's equivalent with:

```
middleware = logStdoutDev >> (staticPolicy $ addBase "static")
```

So, What monad has been used? The `middleware` has type `Application -> Application`. So it's monad reader `(->) Application`.

The expression `logStdoutDev >> (staticPolicy $ addBase "static")` equivalent with `\r -> (\_ -> (staticPolicy $ addBase "static") r) (logStdoutDev r)`. Or if simplify, we'll get: `\r -> (staticPolicy $ addBase "static") r`.

You should to do like this:

```
middleware = logStdoutDev . (staticPolicy $ addBase "static")
```